# Material-UI Menu shakes after opening

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is my sample code. Even if I use this sample code from the material UI website. When I open the menu it shakes a bit. It's kind of like all the menu item is shake upwards. Any idea how to fix it?

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button aria-controls="simple-menu" aria-haspopup="true" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You must have some styles interfering with the menu. Did you check developer tools?

Comment: it works well in my chrome browser, runs it to different browsers. maybe some installed extensions on your browsers affect your CSS style. that's happened for me with Grammarly Extention on chrome.